# Overloading assignment operator when the object is on the right-hand side of the assignment

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Given the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T value;
    Wrapper(T val) : value(val) {}
}

int main() {
    Wrapper<int> x(42);
    int y = x; // need solution for y = x.value
    return 0;
 }
```

Is there a way to implement the assignment

```
int y = x;
```

so that it means y = x.value .

I know that overloading the assignment operator itself is not possible because it applies to the object on the left side of the assignment and friend function with two arguments is not allowed by the standard.

If this is not possible by overloading any other operator, or by using some special tricks, how would you implement this, except by invoking the get method provided by the Wrapper class such as:

```
int y = x.get();
```

Comment: I have accepted JaredPar's answer, but I am open for further suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just provide an implicit conversion to `T`

```
operator T() { return value; }
```

This will cause the assignment to function because the compiler will attempt to convert the right side of the assignment to `T`.  The implicit conversion will allow that to succeed

Note that this will cause other conversions to work besides assignment.  For example it will now be possible to pass `Wrapper<T>` instances as `T` parameters.  That may or may not work for your particular scenario

Comment: @Diggy note that this still doesn't make it act the same as an `int`.  Try calling `void foo( long x )` with `x`.

Comment: @Yakk there are issues with the implicit conversion but I don't believe what you've listed is one of them.  Calling `foo(x)` as you declared will work with my implicit conversion operator

Comment: @Yakk True. However it may be sufficient for my scenario. I need to confirm further that it does not cause any problems in other places as Jared has suggested ("it will now be possible to pass `Wrapper<T>` instances as `T` parameters").

Comment: @JaredPar Can you name the issues with the implicit conversion?

Comment: @Diggy the biggest issue that can arise is when `T` is `bool`. Allowing implicit conversions to `bool` can lead to some surprising behavior.  This blog post details everything that can go wrong http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html

Comment: @Diggy: The common concern with conversions is that you cannot tell the compiler *allow conversions only when I want it*. Which means that suddenly different operations for which you might expect an error actually compile but probably won't do what you want. Or some other constructs for which you *clearly* know what should happen fail to work due to ambiguities arising from the extra conversions. Say you want to implement addition for `Wrapper`, then `1 + w` becomes ambiguous, should it convert `w` to `int`, or `1` to `Wrapper<int>`?